# Explorer died and the stuff is gone. Bug?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I play this game for a while in the "normal" mode. I recently décide to start over with the survival mode. So there's my question.

I sent a explorer in the wasteland with a weapon 22-23 and 8 stimpacks. He survived for 8 hours without using any of them. Before sleep i called him back. He still hadnt use the stimpack. When i open the game this morning, he was dead, all his stuff was gone and the 22-23.
Weapon he was equiped with too. How to fix this bug? I have already move out the body. Is it a bug or is it the survival mode?

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing survival mode for a while, and have a vault of 90 dwellers. It got wiped from over 50 to 3 at one point, but we were able to rebuild.

**Death While Exploring**

If you send out a dweller without a pet, and they die, then you lose all your stuff. That's not a bug, it's how it works. Who would bring the stuff back?

If you send them *with* a pet, then the pet brings the stuff back. Always send explorers out with pets, even if the pet's buff doesn't help them explore.

**Death While Returning**

However, it sounds like you called your dweller back before they died. This should never happen. Dwellers don't take damage while returning, and therefore don't need to use stimpacks and can't die.

So, either you didn't successfully tell them to return, or some sort of bug occurred.

Once you recall a dweller, the exploration window should say something like "Returning to Vault Xh Xm". If it doesn't, they weren't recalled.

If it was a bug, it may have been related to your phone's internal clock. Did you change timezones or reset the clock or something?

**Next Steps**

Since you're playing on survival mode, there's no way to revive the dweller. You're going to lose dwellers occasionally, but nobody's irreplaceable. Nothing to panic about. Like I said at the outset, I once lost more than 90% of my vault in a few minutes, and we're back and stronger than ever.

It's more unfortunate that you seem to have lost the weapon. Send a pet with your explorer next time, and you should at least be able to avoid losing the items.

Comment: Sounds like the explorer died after being recalled, which unless the game has changed recently, shouldn't happen. Once they're on their way back, they should not encounter anything dangerous and just make it back to the vault entrance unscathed.

Comment: @TimS. You're right. I missed the "before sleep I called him back".

Comment: Does the pet bring ALL items or just the explorer's equipment?

Comment: @John All the items the explorer found, the caps, and the equipment the explorer was wearing.

Comment: It's important to note that sometimes, if you quit the game too quickly after doing an action, that action may not be saved.